# Basic Javascript map, filter question in array

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to get things with `collectionId` that match those in the list.
In other words, I want to get the desired result. How can I do it?? please help me....

```
const music_list = {
  "resultCount": 50,
  "results": [{
      "collectionId": 123,
      "ArtistId": "BLACKPINK"
    },
    {
      "collectionId": 456,
      "ArtistId": "BTS"
    },
    {
      "collectionId": 789,
      "ArtistId": "CARDIBI"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
const list = [123, 142, 118];
```

In this situation, Desired result = `[{"collectionId":123, "ArtistId": "BLACKPINK"}]`

Comment: filter and includes

Answer (score 2):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the list to the relevant objects - for each ID, you will try to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the corresponding object in the results array. At the end, you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the missing elements.

```js
const result = list
  .map(id => music_list.results.find(item => item.collectionId === id))
  .filter(item => item)
```

How it works: `music_list.results.find(item => item.collectionId === 123)` would return the item in `music_list.results` that has `collectionId: 123` (or `undefined` if no such item exists). Furthermore, `list.map(id => ...something...)` would apply the `...something...` to each `id` in the `list` and return a new array with the results. So here we map the IDs to the matching objects in your results array. At the end, we use `filter` to remove elements that are falsy (`undefined` is falsy), i.e. remove the missing elements from the result (without that, it would return something like `[{ ... }, undefined, undefined]`).

You can see it in action here:

```js
const music_list = {
  "resultCount": 50,
  "results": [
    {
      "collectionId": 123,
      "ArtistId": "BLACKPINK"
    },
    {
      "collectionId": 456,
      "ArtistId": "BTS"
    },
    {
    "collectionId": 789,
    "ArtistId": "CARDIBI"
    }
  ]
}

const list = [123, 142, 118];

const result = list
  .map(id => music_list.results.find(item => item.collectionId === id))
  .filter(item => item);

console.log(result);
```